# How to setup accounts for Integrated Security with SQL Server and ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

My connection string:

```
connectionString="Server=mydomain.com;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
```

Error Message:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

How can I setup IIS and SQL Server properly to work with Integrated Security when they are on the same machine? And how about when they are on different remote machines?

It is not an option to expose username and password in connection string.

Answer (score 3):

You have to start your application pool with a NT Account (or service account), and give that account permission on the SQL server.
You can do this by going into Advanced settings of the application pool in IIS

Your connection string will then look something like this...
If they are on the same machine

```
SERVER=.[\<INSTANCE_NAME>];DATABASE=xxxx;Integrated Security=True
```

If SQL is on a remote machine

```
SERVER=<SERVER_NAME>[\<INSTANCE_NAME>];DATABASE=xxxx;Integrated Security=True
```